# Neo4j 1.9 HA - Too many HA channels

Tags: neo4j

We have a neo4j configuration with mostly pure defaults, other than listing the hosts to connect to. It's a 1.9.0 enterprise, HA with 3 nodes. We ran into some issues running a light load, and we see this in the messages.log file:

```
2013-08-02 20:49:12.017+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.h.c.m.SlaveClient]: Opened a new channel to neo4j02.xxx.com/10.12.200.43:6361
2013-08-02 20:49:12.019+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.h.c.m.SlaveClient]: Opened a new channel to neo4j02.xxx.com/10.12.200.43:6361
2013-08-02 20:49:12.019+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.h.c.m.SlaveClient]: Opened a new channel to neo4j02.xxx.com/10.12.200.43:6361
2013-08-02 20:49:12.019+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.h.c.m.SlaveClient]: Opened a new channel to neo4j02.xxx.com/10.12.200.43:6361
2013-08-02 20:49:12.020+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.h.c.m.SlaveClient]: Opened a new channel to neo4j02.xxx.com/10.12.200.43:6361
2013-08-02 20:49:12.020+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.h.c.m.SlaveClient]: Opened a new channel to neo4j02.xxx.com/10.12.200.43:6361
2013-08-02 20:49:12.021+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.h.c.m.SlaveClient]: Opened a new channel to neo4j02.xxx.com/10.12.200.43:6361
2013-08-02 20:49:12.022+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.h.c.m.SlaveClient]: Opened a new channel to neo4j02.xxx.com/10.12.200.43:6361
2013-08-02 20:49:12.022+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.h.c.m.SlaveClient]: Opened a new channel to neo4j02.xxx.com/10.12.200.43:6361
2013-08-02 20:49:12.023+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.h.c.m.SlaveClient]: Opened a new channel to neo4j02.xxx.com/10.12.200.43:6361
2013-08-02 20:49:12.023+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.h.c.m.SlaveClient]: Opened a new channel to neo4j02.xxx.com/10.12.200.43:6361
2013-08-02 20:49:12.024+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.h.c.m.SlaveClient]: Opened a new channel to neo4j02.xxx.com/10.12.200.43:6361
2013-08-02 20:49:12.024+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.h.c.m.SlaveClient]: Opened a new channel to neo4j02.xxx.com/10.12.200.43:6361
```

To count these up for just one minute:

```
$ grep "Opened" messages.log | grep "20:49" | wc -l
2478
```

That seems like way too much. Is there something we're doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you check if this is still an issue with Neo4j 1.9.2 ?

Comment: We aren't seeing it with neo4j 1.9.2, however, we are seeing catastrophic instability with the HA cluster. We can't even keep it up for 8 hours without the cluster getting into a state where one or more nodes' haRole is "UNKNOWN" and the cluster dies.